# how to create a cuda shared library used in python

Tags: python, cuda, pycuda

I have created a C shared library which is used in python it works perfectly when i test it.
I compile like this:

```
 gcc -shared -std=c99 -I/usr/include/python2.6 -fPIC -lpython2.6 -opymod.so pymod.c
```

I have a cuda source code "pymod.cu" which is the same as "pymod.c" and i really don't know how to compile it with nvcc.

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to first compile using `nvcc`, then build the shared library using `gcc`:

```
nvcc -c test.cu -o test.o -Xcompiler -fPIC 
gcc -shared -fPIC -o libtest.so test.o
```